# Problema al crear/escribir archivos de cualquier formato en PHP

Tags: php, archivo

Quiero crear un archivo muy básico en el que guarde los datos del formulario en PHP, pero no me crea el archivo txt. Un compañero me pasó su carpeta con su ejercicio y sí paso mi archivo PHP a su carpeta, sí crea el txt al meter los datos, pero fuera de ella el mismo código no funciona.
Entiendo que igual es algún problema de permisos? Donde podría mirar?

Todavía estoy empezando en esto y no se donde localizar el problema cuando ambas carpetas están en public_html

Este es el código PHP y envio pantallazos para que veais que el código se ejecuta pero no crea en mi carpeta pero sí en la que me pasó el compañero.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNSzJ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEqK5.jpg

```
<?php
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

$info = $nombre. " ".$apellido;
$archivo =fopen("nombres.txt","w");
fputs($archivo, $info);
fclose($archivo),
echo ("correcto");
?>
```

Comment: Primero, puedes indicarnos ¿cuál es tu sistema operativo?
Segundo, y sin que tenga una relación directa con tu pregunta, en los ficheros PHP omite el cierre PHP al final de los mismos, es contrario al estandar PSR-2 (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ apdo 2.2) y puede causar problemas.

Comment: Estoy usando Ubuntu. la versión 20.04.3 LTS. Tomo nota de la omisión del cierre, en clase no nos habían indicado eso. Gracias!

Comment: Solo para probar si es un problema de permisos (ya te digo yo que sí). Asígnale todos los permisos al directorio donde vas a crear / modificar el fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias controlar el resultado de las funciones para asi comprobar que sucede.

```
<?php
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

$info = $nombre. " ".$apellido;
$archivo =fopen("nombres.txt","w");
if(!$archivo){ 

     echo "no se creo el archivo, revise los permisos";
     var_dump(fileperms(getcwd())); //Muestra permisos directorio actual
}
fputs($archivo, $info);
fclose($archivo),
echo ("correcto");
?>
```

veo que estas en ubuntu si no me equivoco, usa chmod como root para modificar los permisos o revisa esto https://askubuntu.com/questions/227725/public-html-permissions-for-local-development

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente tal como dice Orici y John, mi problema era los permisos que tenía en la carpeta y ahora al probar ya crea el archivo txt sin problema.

Dejo el pantallazo de como hacer el cambio de permisos por si alguna persona está en el mismo problema.

Muchas gracias a los dos!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaGdG.png

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)